# My function not working 'name.exe has stopped working'

Tags: c, function

The program stops and I get a "merge.exe has stopped working" message. I simplefied everything but the problem seems to occur when calling the function...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define br 1000
int sort(int *list[],int broi);
int merge(int list1[],int list2[],int broi1,int broi2);
int main()
{
int i,n,m,a1[br],a2[br],a;
printf("gimme n: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("gimme m: ");
scanf("%d",&m);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("gimme element %d ot list1: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&a1[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    printf("gimme element %d ot list2: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&a2[i]);
}
sort(&a1,n);
sort(&a2,m);
merge(a1,a2,n,m);
return 0;
}
int sort(int *list[],int broi)
{
int i,j,c;
for (i = 0; i < broi-1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < broi-i-1; j++)
    {
        if (*list[j] > *list[j+1])
        {
            c=*list[j];
            *list[j]=*list[j+1];
            *list[j+1]=c;
        }
    }
}
return 1;
}
int merge(int list1[],int list2[],int broi1,int broi2)
{
printf(" AAAAAA");
return 1;
}
```

In the `sort()` function is pretty self-explanatory and it even works!
But whatever I put in `merge()` it just won't won't work and it breaks the whole program.

Comment: Your sort functions certainly do not work. Please take a look at the compiler warnings. Function `sort` is expecting an array of pointers, not an array of integers.

Comment: `int i,n,m,a1[br],a2[br],a;` I stop here, this is unreadable. Please do NOT declare more than one variable by line and only declare them when needed, this will make you a better programmer.

Comment: ..and give them useful names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int *list[]` makes `list` an array of pointers to `int`. In your `main` function `&a1` (for example) create a pointer to an array of `int`, of type `int (*)[1000]`. `int**` (from the first) is not the same as `int (*)[1000]`.

Simple solution? Don't pass a pointer to the array! This is very seldom needed.

And anyway because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) an expression like `*list[i]` is the same as `*(list[i])`, and if you have a pointer to an array you want `(*list)[i]`. So, many wrongs don't make a right.

Your compiler should have been shouting warnings about this to you.

Answer (score 1):

*In the sort() function is pretty self-explanatory and it even works! ?* NO it won't work. Read the compiler warning by compiling with `-Wall` it says

> reo.c:4:5: note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int *’ as you are passing address of `a1` & catching with array of pointer. Instead just pass array name and catch with pointer.

Make function call looks like

```
sort(a1,n);/*just pass the array name */
sort(a2,m);
```

And definition of `sort()`

```
int sort(int *list,int broi){ /* take list is ptr variable */
        int i,j,c;
        for (i = 0; i < broi-1; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < broi-i-1; j++) {
                        if (list[j] > list[j+1]) {
                                c=list[j];
                                list[j]=list[j+1];
                                list[j+1]=c;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: I didn't say it was perfect but it works. It sorts both lists it just gives me a bunch  of warnings.That's not the problem i'm trying to solve, I'm a lot more concerned about everything breaking when calling merge

Comment: what do you mean by _everything breaking when calling merge_  ? Also your `merge()` contains nothing.

Comment: _it just gives me a bunch of warnings ?_ I just given `sort()` definition. you need to change `sort()` declaration above `main()` also  and there are some unused variable as pointed by @Stragateur in comments

Comment: @provalvalval if the sorting code "worked" that was a fluke. It crashed when I tried it, because your function arguments are incorrect, as advised by the warnings. Saying "it worked so it must be all right" is a false conclusion: there is nothing wrong with the `merge` code – the error is in the `sort` code.